# How can I use less in create-react-app as variables

Tags: reactjs, less, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app with  `react-app-rewire-less` , `react-app-rewired`

After a fresh install, I found less is not working as I expected.

**use `className="header"` works fine, but `className={styles.header}` is not working.**

Here is my `config-overrides.js`

```
const rewireLess = require('react-app-rewire-less');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {

config = rewireLess.withLoaderOptions({
       javascriptEnabled: true
   })(config, env);
   return config;
};
```

**here is my App.js,just change `import './App.css';` to `import styles from './App.less';`,and use `styles.header` for header style**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import styles from './App.less';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className={styles.header}>
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

also changed `App.css` to 'App.less' and `App-header` to `header`,and `react-script`

Comment: google a little,I think it's css module problem.Does anyone know how to add css modules config for less in react-app-rewire-less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's less module problem.
Just `npm install --save-dev react-app-rewire-less-modules`

change your `**.less` file to `**.module.less`

change your config file

```
const rewireLess = require("react-app-rewire-less-modules");
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config = rewireLess.withLoaderOptions({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  })(config, env);
  return config;
};
```